# SharedPreferences are shown only after restarting the activity

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, refresh, sharedpreferences

Hello Together I startet to write my first Android app and I tried to use the SharedPreferences to have the possibility to store some strings.
I can Type in different names and in the onStop() I put them into the SharedPreferences and after that i make a commit. Has someone a solution that Preferences are shown on the next Activity immediatly? Because at the moment I have to switch back to the Activity where I Typed in the names and if I immediatly switch back to the Activity where the names shall be shown they appear.

```
protected void onStop() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = set.edit();
    for(int x=0;x<counterM;x++){
            edit.putString("playerM"+x, playersMale.get(x));
        }
    for(int x=0;x<counterF;x++){
            edit.putString("playerF"+x, playersFemale.get(x));
        }
    edit.putInt("counter", counterF + counterM);
    edit.commit();
    super.onStop();

}
```

and here is the onCreate() where I load  the name...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    set = this.getSharedPreferences("MY_COUNT",0);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.decisionscreen);
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = set.getInt("counter",1000);
    int x = r.nextInt(i);
    name = set.getString("playerM"+x, "no Players found");
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameView);
    t.setText(name+" "+i);
    dareButton();
    truthButton();
}
```

I hope someone can figure out what my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the shared preferences editor stuff in the onPause override. It will be called as soon as you switch the activity.

Comment: That's it... I just thought that the description of the onPause Method is a bit confusing...